# Strip <?xml and <!DOCTYPE from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string in Javascript and need to remove the `<?xml ... ?>` and `<!DOCTYPE .... ]>` tags. Can not convert it to a dom because the BR tags error as not being closed - and not able to edit the actual content.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;">]><div>Blah<br> Blah</div>
```

Trying to do it with .replace but can't quite seem to get there

```
    text.replace(/\<\?xml.+\?\>/g, '');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `replace()` works for the `<?xml ... ?>` part.

To remove the `<!DOCTYPE .... ]>` part as well you can do:

```
text.replace(/\<\?xml.+\?\>|\<\!DOCTYPE.+]\>/g, '');
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/9fKnd/1/

Answer (score 5):

you can use this regex:

```
text.replace(/\<(\?xml|(\!DOCTYPE[^\>\[]+(\[[^\]]+)?))+[^>]+\>/g, '');
```

that works with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;">]><div>Blah<br> Blah</div>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div>Blah<br> Blah</div>

<!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;">]><div>Blah<br> Blah</div>
```

Comment: So, what advantage does it offer over darkajax's answer from 8 minutes ago?

Comment: I'm more generic. If the content changes my regex continues to work.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has unnecessary escaping (extra back slashes, making an ugly regex uglier), this works too:

```js
const text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html [<!ENTITY amp "&#38;#38;">]><div>Blah<br> Blah</div>'

console.log(text)

const afterReplace = text.replace(/<\?xml.+\?>|<!DOCTYPE.+]>/g, '')

console.log(afterReplace)
```